# Reset Rx Js fromEvent observable after subscribe

Tags: rxjs, observable

I have mousemove event:

```
 fromEvent(document, 'mousemove').pipe(
   filter(e => e.target !== this.formElement.nativeElement),
   filter(_ => this.form.valid),
   take(1),
   mergeMap((): any => this.confirm()),
   ).subscribe();


confirm() {
   this.snack.open('sure', 'yes').onAction()
   .subscribe(_ => {
      this.createNoteService.create();
    })
 }
```

After confirming the snack button I want the mouse event to start working again.

Is it possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this only works for you the first time, is because you have `take(1)` which ends the observable after one value is received.

Also, your `confirm()` method should return observable; don't subscribe inside the function; `mergeMap` will automatically subscribe / unsubscribe for you.

However, instead of `mergeMap`, you can use [`exhaustMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/exhaustmap).  This will only allow a single inner subscription at a time.  It will ignore any incoming emissions until its current source completes:

```js
fromEvent(document, 'mousemove').pipe(
  filter(e => e.target !== formElement.nativeElement),
  filter(_ => form.valid),
  exhaustMap(() => confirm()),
).subscribe();

function confirm() {
  return snack.open('sure', 'yes').onAction().pipe(
    tap(() => this.createNoteService.create())
  );
}
```